# How to get values of dynamic text boxes

Tags: asp.net, forms, viewstate, pageload

How can i get the values of dynamically created text boxes that i have reload every time a user adds a new text box?

Right now what I have is a form with a few text boxes, and an add button, now when the a user clicks add button, it creates another section with a few more text boxes, but now if the user had typed something in one of the text boxes before he clicked add, how can i store that information and make sure it comes back up when the page reloads?

Thank you,

Comment: Could you provide some code? Usually the Viewstate take care of this

Comment: As Maxime wrote, ViewState should handle this for You. Make sure You add those controls on postbacks and assign unique value to `ID` to each of the text boxes. You can find more information about dynamic controls and ViewState here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i.

Comment: Yeah, i can get the controls and display them no problem,through viewstate, but the issue lies when i try to display the value of that text box, someone suggested setting cookies, but how can i iterate through them through code behind, if i assign them trough javascript?